# Unauthorized Page Error When Using Id Parameter

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I'm building a site. I have a page that shows cases to portal users. Users can click on any case's id and see the detail. The thing is that when I call the case page with id, an unauthorized error occurs.

I'm calling case page as case?id={c.Id} in an HTML a tag. Site direction occurs, I can see the constructor runs well, produces data but at last Unauthorized page happens!

I'im using a StandartController in my extension and standartController="Case" in Case page.

What could be the possible reason of this? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: did you check the debug logs to see whats happening ? this post might help you http://www.tgerm.com/2010/10/debugging-sites-authorization-required.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys, I found out my problem. It turned out that it is not a problem, just misunderstanding of me. It seems that the key point of view must be like this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/44983/11466

Answer (score 0):

This is normally due to a missing permission in the profile.

Does the profile for the currently logged in user have access to the VF page you created? If so, I would also check for access to the case object, fields, etc.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked. All needed VF pages are enabled. By the way, I can open /case link within site manually. All values are coming with null values. So, page is enabled. But when I add the ?id= parameter, Unauthorized page keep coming. Case object fields are set to visible, also. There is no id field in the list.